# proxy: pass request body failed

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-proxy

I'm trying to enable proxy virtualhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

  ServerName xxxxx.domain.tdl
  SSLProxyEngine On
  SSLProxyCheckPeerCN on

  ProxyPass / https://localhost:1234
  ProxyPassReverse / https://localhost:1234

</VirtualHost>
```

But i've an 500 err and my error.log (apache2) display:

> [Tue Jan 03 15:41:42 2012] [error] (502)Unknown error 502: proxy: pass
> request body failed to [::1]:1234 (localhost)
>
> [Tue Jan 03 15:41:42
> 2012] [error] proxy: pass request body failed to [::1]:1234
> (localhost) from 82.252.xxx.xx ()

Missing some parameters ?

Answer (score 3):

```
ProxyPass / https://localhost:1234/
ProxyPassReverse / https://localhost:1234/
```

Try that instead.  Slashes matching is important.

Comment: Hello, same error with slashes.

Comment: Ok.  Is the service on port 1234 actually listening on IPv6?  Try `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`.  Also, what's the subject name of the certificate on that port?  If it's not an exact match with that hostname, the connect will fail - and if you make the change to force IPv4 localhost (127.0.0.1) then it'll really fail.  Probably just turn off `SSLProxyCheckPeerCN`.

Comment: "Probably just turn off SSLProxyCheckPeerCN": Yes, it's working now =). But now the service behind localhost:1234 throw an error about cookies :/ (Your browser does not support cookies, which are required for this web server to work in session authentication mode) I think its the ProxyPass, service work fine without it.

Comment: didn't helped for me, any other ideas?

Comment: @childno.de It'd be best if you open a new question with your specific configuration and log entries so that we can take a look at that.

Answer (score 3):

If the browser is setting the cookies for xxxxx.domain.tdl and the server is returning them for localhost or a locally defined domain, you might have a mismatch. You can use [`ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassreversecookiedomain) to rewrite the cookies.

Since they're both on /, you probably won't need `ProxyPassReverseCookiePath`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`, probably your app is not running IPv6